# Django IntegrityError NOT NULL constraint failed not use null and blank

Tags: django, django-views

IntegrityError at /blablabla

NOT NULL constraint failed: product_product.category_id

Null=True, blank=True is suggested as a solution to this error.

But I don't want it to be null and blank. How do I solve it without adding blank and null?
I previously defined the product list manually.

views.py:

```
Product.objects.create(code=product[1], 
   variant=product[2], header=str(product[3]) +" "+ str(product[2]),
   category_id=product[4], description=product[5],
  is_opportunity=product[6],is_outlet=product[7],discount=product[8],     price=product[12], image=str(product[1]) + "-" + str(product[2]) +".jpg")
```

models.py:

```
 class Product(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True)
    variant = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    header = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=False, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_opportunity = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    is_outlet = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, editable=False, max_length=150)
    discount = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True)
```

Comment: Providing a value that is different from `None`/`NULL`.

Comment: then you shouldn't left this field *null*

Comment: I don't leave it blank anyway but it gives this error :) I used objects.create() func.

Comment: Ok so show your code, could be another field causing this error but you are not helping us without any snippet of code

Comment: You are right. Sorry. Wait pls.

Comment: I added snippet of code

Comment: Looks like `product[4]` is `None`.

Comment: product[4] is "1". I printed in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways of doing it :

1. Providing a value at save time, could be anything from a date to the username
2. Set a default value to your field, for example :

   `models.Charfield(default="Something"`)

Comment: All my variables have default values

Comment: The error code is clear, you forgot to set a value for modal_modal.examples, so no, you don't have default values for everything, then again you are not showing any code...